# FFmpeg works on terminal not with PHP exec

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, php

If I execute a Ffmpeg command from terminal, I get the desired result:

```
ffmpeg  -i src.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv
```

Terminal's output:

```
...
video:3404kB audio:1038kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.966904%
```

And `video.flv` is created correctly.

Then, if called via PHP exec:

```
exec("ffmpeg  -i src.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv", $o, $v);
var_dump($o);
var_dump($v);
```

The output is this:

```
array(0) { } int(1)
```

And no file is created. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

I can `exec('whoami')` with no problems and I have used the FFmpeg full path as well: `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`

Comment: Maybe exec() only captures stdout in `output`, not stderr.

Comment: FFmpeg produces very weird output — you have to redirect both stdout and stderr to get everything AFAIK.

Comment: I do not get the desired flv file created, so something is def. not working. Definitively the most urgent matter at this point ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use `exec` instead of `shell_exec`
the point is that environement of exec don't know about any FFmpeg executable, but `shell_exec`* does, becuase it uses env. of the bash/shell

Ths solution is to use the full path to FFmpeg executable, eg. `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`

Comment: No, the user said they tried `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` as well.

Comment: we had same issue half year ago, solution, described above, solved the problem, what about "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", maybe - bin folder is not correct !?..

Comment: `exec ` with full path `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` worked for me, i found the path using `which ffmpeg`

Answer (score 1):

add `2>&1` to the end of the command and it will work:

```
exec("ffmpeg  -i src.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv 2>&1", $o, $v);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the full path for `ffmpeg`, use `/full/path/to/src.mp4` and `/full/path/to/video.flv`

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem, first make sure that the ffmpeg.exe or directory is in the windows path, then restart your apache server to ensure that php found the ffmpeg command. After this i can use ffmpeg with both options exec and shell_exec

Answer (score 0):

In my case, due to using root user to create the folder, the php user didn't have write permission. Giving it write permission worked. For some reason I wasn't getting any output with `shell_exec` but the following shows everything and finds the `ffmpeg` binaries for you.

```
<?php
$dir = __DIR__;

//Find ffmpeg binaries
$ffmpeg =trim(shell_exec("which ffmpeg"));

//resize input.png to 120px width
$command = "$ffmpeg -i '$dir/input.png' -vf scale=120:-1 '$dir/output.png'";
echo $command . "<br>";

//run command and output streams to vars
exec("$command 2>&1", $o, $v);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($o);
print_r($v);
echo "</pre>";
```